# JQuery only clone each tr of a thead table

Tags: jquery, clone

I just want to clone the html tr and th's, but not capture the outer thead /thead elements.

```
<thead id="justCloneTR">   // don't clone
 <tr id="Vehicle_1">       // clone
  <th>1</th>              // clone
  <th>2</th>              // clone
 </tr>                    // clone
</thead>                  // don't clone

<div id="putCloneHere"></div>
```

JS

```
$('#justCloneTR').clone('tr').appendTo('#putCloneHere');
```

Comment: [`$('#Vehicle_1').clone();`](http://api.jquery.com/clone)

Comment: Damn!  that easy.  Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `id` to the `tr` then you can just use this.

```
$('#Vehicle_1').clone();
```

`.clone()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Remember after cloning you should change the id of cloned element before you add it to DOM because you should not have 2 elements with same id.

Try this.

```
var id = 'Vehicle_' + parseInt($('#Vehicle_1').attr('id').match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;
$('#Vehicle_1').clone().attr('id', id).appendTo('#putCloneHere');
```